# Android after change typeface fontstyle not working

Tags: android, fonts, styles, typeface

I apply a bangla(a language) font as typeface in textview, Text style was set as bold but
the english part of the text is coming as bold but bangla part is not bold, i want to bold full text

> ```
>  TextView tv = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.textvie2);
>
>     Typeface  mFace = Typeface.createFromAsset(this.getAssets(),"Siyamrupali_1_01.ttf");
>     tv.setTypeface(mFace);
> ```

This was code in activity
and in xml it was

```
<TextView
            android:id="@+id/textvie2"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="fill_parent"
            android:padding="10dp"
            android:textSize="25sp"
            android:textStyle="bold" >
```

so if i set a bangla-english mixed text only english is getting bold, bangla font not getting bold, why?

Comment: The information to make a font bold is part of the font itself, its not done in the view class.  Are you sure the font you used for Bangla has bolding information?

Comment: i dont know, but i used this font in iphone and can make bold

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Change your code as below

```
Typeface  mFace = Typeface.createFromAsset(this.getAssets(),"Siyamrupali_1_01.ttf");
    tv.setTypeface(mFace,Typeface.Bold);
```

Comment: wow,  its worked, thank u , feeling stupid now. but why it was bold for english and not for bangla